# Are elements of D all positive in an $LDL^T$ decomposition of a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix, and its Cholesky Decomposition be $LDL^T$. Are all elements on D's diagonal positive? What if $A$ is semi-positive definite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix $A$ represents a quadratic form $q$ w.r.t. a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assuming $A$ positive definite you assume that the quadratic form $q$ is positive definite. If $A = L D L^{\top}$ then $D$ represents $q$ with respect another basis $(b_1,\cdots,b_n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The diagonal $d_{ii}$ of $D$ are the numbers $d_{ii} =q(b_i,b_i)$. So the assumption on $q$ to be definite positive implies $d_{ii} > 0$. If you assume $A$ to be semidefinite positive then you can claim, by the argument, that $d_{ii} \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer for the first part, 1 up! However, when $A$ is only semidefinite, we don't know if $L$ is invertible. Can you still claim D be a semidefinite positive quadratic form?

Comment: If $L$ is not invertible the $D$ can have some negative numbers in the diagonal. I you want I can edit my answer and show you an explicit example.

Comment: Holonomia, yes, please do, much appreciated. But now I am thinking, maybe my second question is an ill one - a semidefinite positive matrix does not have a $LDL^T$ decomposition because $L$ has to be unitriangular which is impossible when $A$ is not invertible. What do you think?

Comment: Actually, you are right since in $LDL^{\top}$ decomposition the matrix $L$ is invertible. The example I had in mind was not a "true" Cholesky, here it is :  $A  = diag(1,0) , D = diag(1,-1) , L = diag(1,0) $

Comment: Accepted your answer. Maybe you can edit the answer so that we are not confusing people that only read the answer itself.

Comment: You are right I will edit the answer and remove the word "invertible" since people working with Cholesky decomposition had always in mind $L$ unitriangular hence invertible.